# Exiting all long trades when entering short trade

Tags: pine-script, trading, pine-script-v5

I use pyramiding. Lets say I have now 3 long trades open and then short trade condiction appears. Short trade entries, but at the same moment all opposite trades (in this example long trades) close.

How to have both long and short trades being open simultaneously?

Answer (score 0):

You can call the `strategy.close_all()` function before you open your short trade.

> It is a command to exit from current market position making it flat.
> If there is no open market position by the moment the command is
> triggered, the command will not come into effect.

```
strategy("closeAll Demo", overlay=false)
strategy.entry("buy", strategy.long, when = open > close)
strategy.close_all(when = open < close, comment = "close all entries")
plot(strategy.position_size)
```

Comment: You did not understand me correctly.  What I wrote is what IS HAPPENING NOW, not what I want to be. I want exact opposite.

Comment: You cannot have both longs and shorts being open simultaneously in Pine.

Answer (score 0):

I think, you can use same strategy twice, one is just for long, the other is just for short.

Comment: This is as a last resort, I am trying to do it in 1 strategy.